# Memory allocation types by moment of lvalue binding in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory, lvalue

I am having some trouble with a homework assignment. I have put in a lot of research but have gotten stuck. The assignment is as follows:

> Develop and implement an example in which you show the different
> variable types the assigned language implements, according to their
> classification by the moment of binding with the lvalue.

I have researched the different types and have come to the following:

> Variables can be divided in 4 types based on the moment of binding with the lvalue.
>
> - Static: Memory is allocated before runtime and the variables last in memory during the entire execution of the program
> - Automatic (or semi-static): Memory is allocated when a variable's scope is loaded, and deallocated when leaving the scope.
> - Dynamic: Memory is only allocated when needed during execution. (I take this as meaning that instead of allocatin at for example the
>   function call, it allocates when the actual variable declaration is
>   run). Memory is deallocated when needed. Pointers are an example I've
>   found of this.
> - Semi-dynamic: I havent found a clear definition of this, but an example I've seen is arrays which size is unknown until runtime.

I have examples of each in Pascal, but my assigned language for this assignment is Python. I cannot find what types of allocation Python uses. I've seen [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/memory_allocation.html) that Python uses Dynamic allocation, but I am unsure whether this is really dynamic (manual deallocation managed by the garbage collector) or automatic (since the programmer doesnt have to do this manually). I am also uncertain if things like class properties, global variables and constants are static or if they work the same way as the other variables (either automatic/dynamic).

Any insights on the type of memory used by python, or even review of my definitions of each type would be greatly appreciated. As mentioned, I have researched this, but what I have found was either unclear (to me) or about programming specific problems (i.e. how do I manually allocate/deallocate memory in Python) and not which of the types mentioned above Python uses.

Comment: Great question! Without really thinking this through, I can only confirm what you already said: most of memory allocation in Python is dynamic. Even classes (which are simply objects in Python) are created/allocated dynamically. I'll try to think of some edge cases (modules, iteration variables, etc) and post an answer later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some research but can't find any reference to static memory allocation in Python, or more precisely *CPython* : it seems most facets of memory management are not specified by the Python language but left flexible for its implementations to decide.

I believe all of CPython's memory management would be "dynamic" since it's its runtime that manages a private heap (whenever needed) to allocate memory for objects (and as I said in a previous comment, *almost* everything is an object in Python!)

Although not directly related to your question, it is possible to have "typed" allocation in CPython, for example using the [typed array type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html).

Now, PyPy is a different beast. It uses [RPython](http://pypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/coding-guide.html#our-runtime-interpreter-is-rpython) as a runtime interpreter which seems to do fancier things with regards to memory allocation, like analyzing how [user defined classes are used](http://doc.pypy.org/en/release-1.9/translation.html#user-defined-classes-and-instances).

Now I'm not sure if that classifies as automatic allocation, but that might be something to talk about in your report!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look into this! I'll be sure to mention it in my report :) I'll also check with the teacher, if she tells me anything new i'll let you know :)